# php Application Fail to start after compiling and installing with inno setup

Tags: php, inno-setup

I compiled and installed a php program using php desktop and inno setup, the program work on php desktop but failed to start after compiling with inno setup. What could be the problem? because i dont get any errors

Comment: We need more information from you to help debug this. You may also want to try over at Server Fault if this is more application software related.

Comment: *"failed to start"* means what? Is the application working when you copy it somewhere out of development folder and run it manually (not from PHP desktop)? Are you testing the Inno Setup installer on the same machine ore different one? Why [tag:compiler-errors], if you get no errors?

Comment: See [Difference between .exe and the .exe returned from Inno Setup - Installed application fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35050255/850848).

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked turns out using inno setup to create an installer for php desktop app isn't such a great idea. I had to use exeoutput for php to make the desktop application and innosetup to make it's installer and it worked like a charm. Thanks guys.